# How can I use variables declarated in a .scss file (e.g. $blueColor: #ffffff) in a .css file?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I want to declare all of the colors I need to use in a `.scss` file for only call these color variables from my `.css` file.

I tried to put `@import "<.scss file path>"` on the top of the `.css` file, but it doesn't go.

Example:

**mycssfile.css**

```
@import "./myscssfile.scss"

body {

  color: $whiteColor;

}
```

**myscssfile.scss**

```
$whiteColor : #ffffff
```

Could someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: you can't use them in css. Css doesn't support variables, mixins or import. Instead you could use scss everywhere and then transpile them to css

Comment: @Satif CSS does support `@import` since forever, and variables are a new(ish) addition, but support is getting better. Of course it won't work in combination with `scss` without preprocessor / compilation step.

Comment: @Satif thanks! One question more. What is the difference between scss files and css? The browser load the stylesheets on the same way?

Comment: @pawel thanks! One question more. What is the difference between scss files and css? The browser load the stylesheets on the same way?

Comment: @ECF CSS is a natively supported standard for defining styles of HTML documents. SCSS/SASS, and LESS and other are non-standard  languages that need accomanying preprocessor, that takes the code and turns it into a CSS file that can be understood by browsers. Preprocessors are useful for many reasons, one of the most useful being nested syntax. I think most large projects use a preprocessor (I can't remember the last time I wrote "vanilla" CSS for a project).

Comment: @pawel and this preprocessor how it runs? Can I make this process (readd scss, preprocess to css and load by the browser) automatic?

Comment: @ECF of course you can. Here are the docs: https://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: @pawel okey! Thank you very much! I am newer in frontend jajaja

Answer (score 1):

CSS and SCSS files don't mix.

SCSS files are parsed to CSS files before the browser does anything with them. 
You can import SCSS files into other SCSS files if you want.

If you just want to use variables in CSS, you can look at [css variables](https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/).
Since they are variables in actual CSS you can do some pretty neat things with them.

Comment: Thanks! But I need to declarate the color variables in a .scss file. If I can't use/import the scss variables in the css file... probably I am going to transform .css file in a .scss file but I must to search if there is any difference between using .scss file or .css file like main stylesheet file.

Comment: SCSS is a superset of CSS.
So you could copy all your CSS code into a SCSS file and it will work. 

The big difference is that SCSS code needs to be pre-processed. That is something the browser does not do for you. This process can be automated as part of your development setup. 
This result of this preprocessing is standard CSS code that the browser can use to render your page the way you want.

Comment: Okey, thanks! Somebody said to me about the preprecessor... I don´t know how it runs ... but I have a solution at the end jajaja

Answer (score 0):

You can't import an .scss file into a .css file, SCSS needs to be translated into CSS before use.

Comment: thanks! probably substitute .css file with a .scss file